# Unable to cast object of type AsyncStateMachineBox System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult to type System.Threading.Tasks.Task

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, mediatr

I'm very new to ASP.NET Web API and I'm trying to use Entity Framework Core's Dependency Injection to POST data to the API Controller using MediatR pattern. But every time I run my code and it opens Swagger UI, I get an error 500 response saying

> Unable to cast object of type 'AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult,S3E1.Repository.CartItemRepository+<Createitem>d__5]' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[S3E1.Entities.CartItemEntity]'.

First, I added Dependency Injections to Program.cs

```
//Dependency Injection
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDataContext>(contextOptions => contextOptions.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ));

//Connection
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DataConnectionContext>();
```

These are the classes.
AppDataContext.cs

```
public class AppDataContext : DbContext
    {
        
        public AppDataContext(DbContextOptions<AppDataContext> contextOptions) : base(contextOptions) { }

        public DbSet<CartItemEntity> CartItems { get; set; }
      
        public DbSet<OrderEntity> Orders { get; set; }

        public DbSet<UserEntity> Users{ get; set; }
        
    }
```

DataConnectionContext.cs

```
public class DataConnectionContext
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public DataConnectionContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        }

        public IDbConnection CreateConnection() => new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    }
```

Next is making a repository which holds the interface that has the create method.

```
public interface ICartItemRepository
    {
        //public Task<IEnumerable<CartItemEntity>> GetCartItems();
        //public Task<CartItemEntity> GetCartItemEntity(Guid id);

        public Task Createitem(CartItemEntity itemEntity);
    }
```

Then a class that inherits the interface and calls the dependency constructors

```
public class CartItemRepository : ICartItemRepository
    {

private readonly DataConnectionContext _connectionContext;
        private readonly AppDataContext _appDataContext;

        public CartItemRepository(DataConnectionContext connectionContext, AppDataContext appDataContext)
        {
            _connectionContext = connectionContext;
            _appDataContext = appDataContext;
        }

public async Task Createitem(CartItemEntity itemEntity)
        {
            _appDataContext.CartItems.Add(itemEntity);
            await _appDataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            await _appDataContext.CartItems.ToListAsync();
        }
}
```

Next is a command for POST request MediatR pattern

```
public record AddCartItemCommand(CartItemEntity cartItem) : IRequest<CartItemEntity>;
```

and a Handler which manages and returns the method createitem

```
public class AddItemsHandler : IRequestHandler<AddCartItemCommand, CartItemEntity>
    {
        private readonly ICartItemRepository _cartItemRepository;

        public AddItemsHandler(ICartItemRepository cartItemRepository) => _cartItemRepository = cartItemRepository;

        public async Task<CartItemEntity> Handle(AddCartItemCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await (Task<CartItemEntity>) _cartItemRepository.Createitem(request.cartItem);
        }
    }
```

and lastly, in the controller

```
[Route("api/cart-items")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CartItemsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private ISender _sender;

        public CartItemsController(ISender sender) => _sender = sender;


[HttpPost]
        public async Task<CartItemEntity> Post(CartItemEntity cartItemEntity)
        {
            return await _sender.Send(new AddCartItemCommand(cartItemEntity));
        }
}
```

I tried modifying the return object in the handler but every time I change anything it always get the error squiggly line, so I just casted the (Task) after the await. Is this where I went wrong? Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is clear. You can't cast a `VoidTaskResult` to `Task<CartItemEntity>`.

To solve the problem:

1. In `ICartItemRepository`, modify the return type for `Createitem` as `Task<CartItemEntity>`.
2. In `CartItemRepository`, implement `Createitem` method from the `ICartItemRepository` interface. Return the inserted `itemEntity` in the method.
3. Since you have implemented `Task<CartItemEntity> Createitem(CartItemEntity itemEntity)` in the `ICartItemRepository` interface, the casting to `(Task<CartItemEntity>)` is no longer needed, and suggested to be removed.

```cs
public interface ICartItemRepository
{
    ...

    public Task<CartItemEntity> Createitem(CartItemEntity itemEntity);
}
```

```cs
public class CartItemRepository : ICartItemRepository
{
    ...

    public async Task<CartItemEntity> Createitem(CartItemEntity itemEntity)
    {
        _appDataContext.CartItems.Add(itemEntity);
        await _appDataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return itemEntity;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class AddItemsHandler : IRequestHandler<AddCartItemCommand, CartItemEntity>
{
    ...

    public async Task<CartItemEntity> Handle(AddCartItemCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
         return await _cartItemRepository.Createitem(request.cartItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I recently just learned MediatR patterns so the passing of multiple queries and commands to handlers were confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Its mostly related to the asynchronous issue. Try to debug and see if the whole method logic is async or not.

HINT: Sometimes an await or Task <'T'> is missing, a very simple mistake that we do.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).